# Simple console.log not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a very simple `console.log("Hello world");` to see if everything is working with MS Code and live server but I cannot make it happen.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <scirpt src="index.js"></scirpt>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

then, the js code (index.js) which is on the same directory as .html:

**JavaScript**

```
function Person(name){
    name;
    sayHello=function(){
        console.log("Hello"+name);
    }
}

let m=new Person('Michael');
m.sayHello();
```

So, why don't I see any output on the console?

Comment: I get an error. Note that your code is not at all how you define either old-style constructors or ES 2015 classes.

Comment: One part of the problem is a typo: `scirpt` instead of `script`.

Comment: To be honest I didn't realize the typo. Thank you all.
Furthermore, my code is bad but that was not my problem. I stuck on not getting a response from console.log so, I skip correcting the code...sorry for that! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to attached the function (sayHello) as a property to `Person`. You also have misspelled the `script` as `scirpt`:

```js
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello=function(){
    console.log("Hello "+name);
  }
}

let m=new Person('Michael');
m.sayHello();
```

```html
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you *not* realized the script tag is misspell?

Comment: The content of the HTML area in a Stack Snippet is put in the `body` of the generated page. Don't include non-body markup (and script tags that don't load anything).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you assign property to object, the way is to use this.key = value

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello " + name);
  }
}

let m = new Person('Michael');
m.sayHello();
```